# Split HTML into pages, each with header and footer

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, pdf

I have an HTML document that I need to convert to PDF. The problem is that I need to have some header and footer on every page of the converted PDF document.
Because content has a different size (some tables), I can't hardcode height.

The app is written using ASP.NET if that matters.

[image: This is how the PDF look right now]

Can you please suggest some way to handle that problem?

Comment: Create and build the PDF yourself without generating it with html?

Comment: Unfortunately, my task is to convert the existing HTML template to PDF and I can not change this decision

Comment: Then you have to create html that fits per page and add the footers yourself.